# Why longitudinal acoustic phonons (LA) do not have a dipole moment?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phonons

For a phonon mode to be able to emit electromagnetic radiation, it must have a dipole moment.

1. However, it is not intuitive to me why the LA phonon does not have a dipole moment: suppose all atoms in a unit cell are oscillating in phase back and forth relative to the electronic background, isn't this itself a dipole moment? The radiation should came out perpendicular to the oscillatrion direction.
2. Mathematically, when we determine whether a mode "has a dipole moment", what quantity are we actually talking about?
   Thanks.